# Find returns null objects

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have 3 different model classes: Product, ProductCategory and ProductSubcategory. They all have proper DbContext classes defined like:

```
  public class ProductCategoryDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }

    }
```

Now on my Product controller class I want to access those other tables too, so I have there:

```
  public class ProductsController : Controller
    {
        private ProductDBContext db = new ProductDBContext();
        private ProductCategoryDBContext dbCat = new ProductCategoryDBContext();
        private ProductSubcategoryDBContext dbSubcat = new ProductSubcategoryDBContext();
...
}
```

and

```
 public ActionResult Details(int? id)
 {
        Product product = db.Products.Find(1);
        ProductCategory Category = dbCat.ProductCategories.Find(1);
        ProductSubcategory Subcat = dbSubcat.ProductSubcategories.Find(1);
....
}

(I have hardcoded the key values for clarity to make sure that they really are on database.
```

Problem is that the first Find (Products) returns a proper value but two latters are null. Is that because I call from Products controller and is there something I have missed here?

Comment: Just have a single DbContext per database that you're accessing. Create a DbSet per type you're accessing on that context.

Comment: Brilliant! That's what I needed. Learned something new today again TY :)

Answer (score 2):

Each `DbContext` is roughly equivalent to one database. If all of your entities belong to one database or from a Code First perspective, you want them to all be together in one database, then you should only have one context.

I'm completely guessing here, but the mostly likely situation is that since you're working with three context, Entity Framework is looking at three different databases. This can easily occur silently if you're letting it handle database initialization (the default) and have automatic migrations enabled (the default).

Then, you most likely have relationships between these entities. When entities are related, even if they aren't explicitly in a particular context, Entity Framework actually silently adds them to the context and will create tables, etc. for those. In other words, even if you have these entities segregated out into different contexts, if they're related, they're all in every context.

Finally, if you add items to one of these contexts, but not the others, looking at the database, you might assumed that something should be returned, but since they aren't actually in the databases represented by the other contexts, when you query them from those contexts, you get back nothing.

Long and shot, don't split the context up, or if you do, be aware of the implications of that. You should break all direct relationships between entities that are in different contexts. Otherwise, you'll end up right back in this same situation.